# A HTML5 way to declare a fixed row or column in a table?

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a HTML5 way to declare a fixed row or column in a table?

I'm not talking about a JS plug in or a hacky CSS way to do it... I mean something that would work in the future, like:

```
<table style="overflow-y: scroll">
  <tr fixed="fixed"><td>Something</td><td>Something</td>
  <tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td>
  <tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td>
  <tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td>
  <tr><td>Something</td><td>Something</td>
</table>
```

I don't care that it wouldn't be usable for some years, due to not being backwards compatible... it'd just give me faith that some day, people would be able to make fixed rows and fixed columns easily.

TL/DR: Is there a way to declare rows and columns fixed with an attribute, in any future HTML spec, and if not, where do I go to formally suggest it?

Comment: Your pseudo-code is ambiguous. Could you create a mock-up to illustrate your concept?

Answer (score 2):

Fixing rows or columns is a presentational issue and thus in the realm of CSS rather than HTML.

However, HTML has – even in HTML 4 – the `thead` element that *may* be used by browsers to distinguish the header part from the body part of a table and possibly implement the latter as scrollable, while keeping the header part static: “Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or more table body sections, using the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements, respectively. This division enables user agents to support scrolling of table bodies independently of the table head and foot. When long tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be repeated on each page that contains table data.” ([HTML 4.01 on row groups](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-THEAD))

Probably no browser implements such scrolling automatically. It does not seem to be possible to suggest it in CSS either in any direct way, since height allocation in tables has its own rules; you would need to use extra markup and positioning.